# Can you mix Warhammer Fantasy armies?

Tags: house-rules, warhammer-fantasy

My wife is interested in playing Warhammer Fantasy. We've tried to work out what army she'd like to play (we went through all the pieces on the GW website,  and she picked out these ones she likes the look of), and she actually wants to make an army from multiple different armies.  A mix of wood elves,  dwarves,  dark elves.... Etc.

We haven't invested in the rule book yet,  nor any pieces,  but I was wondering if this was possible (in the rules, or by house rules)  before we pick it what to buy. It's likely that she'd only be playing against me,  if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness:

Now Warhammer Fantasy is rebranded to Warhammer Age of Sigmar, that allows you to play with "whatever the heck you want" in any game. But even if you want to play rules hardcorelly, now they are only 4 factions, Order, Chaos, Destruction and Death.

All the armies you named in your question are part of "Order" so, by the new rules, they are completely allowed to be used together.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Warhammer (especially with house rules) is all about figuring out what you can do. Alliances are common, and you can find an alliance matrix in the rule book. More than 3 armies in anything below 1750 pts. (about £400 worth of models) is nigh on impossible, but only if you play by the GW rules. If you wanted to play in tournaments, then you would have to make sure to structure your list well (High Elves and Dark Elves are mortal enemies, so would not be on the same side, for example), but in a friendly home battle, anything is possible! Unlikely alliances give you the chance to make some really great backstory though, so most tournaments would accept heavy alliance lists if the backstory was good. I'm glad you're getting into the hobby, and I'm sure you'll enjoy it.